# how to use slide view control in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Have anyone used slideview ([Slide View](http://slideview.codeplex.com/)) control in windows phone 8.  I have installed nuget ([Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlideView)) but unable to use it in a project. If anyone could provide some links or samples, that would be a great help.

Thanks

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

here are two samples that can be helpful to you :

1. [Control animation while navigating between panes inside a Windows Phone page](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Control_animation_while_navigating_between_panes_inside_a_Windows_Phone_page)
2. [Add side menus to an Windows Phone application (similar to the Facebook app)](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.in/2013/08/add-lateral-menus-to-windows-phone.html)

Comment: I have gone through both these. and tried to implement the slideview control,but ended up in hell lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlideView) package and replace the xaml in your page with the following

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <library:SlideView SelectionChanged="SlideView_OnSelectionChanged">
        <!--Left Panel-->
        <Grid Background="Tomato" Width="400">
        </Grid>

        <!--Main Panel-->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <!--Right Panel-->
        <!--<Grid Background="Firebrick" Width="400" />-->
    </library:SlideView>
</Grid>
```

By the way, you can find a lot of sample in the [Source Code tab of the codeplex projet](http://slideview.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest).